# React Spring Boot App Using Multipart Form Data - Required request part 'file' is not present

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot

After days of attempting to upload a file using a React frontend and Spring Boot backend, I'm coming here to see if anyone can guide me in the right direction.  Everything seems to be in place - I select my file, I see the file properties in the console, and I see form data being passed to the REST API, but I still get an error.

Some React snippets:

```
 const onFileChangeHandler = (e) => {
         e.preventDefault();
         setFileAttachment({
             fileAttachment: e.target.files[0]
         })};

const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('file',fileAttachment)

const requestOptionsInsertNote = {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData
};

<input type="file" name="file" onChange={onFileChangeHandler}/>
```

Some Spring Boot snippets:

```
@PostMapping( "/api/notes/insertNote")
public void insertJournalNote(@RequestPart(value="file") MultipartFile file{
         UploadedFileInfo uploadedFileInfo = new UploadedFileInfo();
    try{
        uploadedFileInfo.setFileData(file.getBytes());
        uploadedFileInfo.setFileType(file.getContentType());
        uploadedFileInfo.setFileName(file.getOriginalFilename());
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}
```

Console log data for console.log(fileAttachment):

```
Object { fileAttachment: File }​
fileAttachment: File { name: "file.jpg", lastModified: 1650655091391, size: 148823, … }​​
lastModified: 1650655091391​​
name: "file.jpg"​​
size: 148823​​
type: "image/jpeg"​​
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

Request sent to rest api:

```
-----------------------------174062142330182702901981377266
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

[object Object]
-----------------------------174062142330182702901981377266--
```

Error message in Intellij:

Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this:

```
setFileAttachment({
         fileAttachment: e.target.files[0]
     })
```

Needed to be this:

```
setFileAttachment(e.target.files[0])
```

It's always the little things

Answer (score 1):

You should enable multipart in application.properties file:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size = -1
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=-1
```

Also, don't forget to set the `'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'` in request header while sending your request.

---

EDIT:You need to define the CommonMultipartResolver Bean.

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipart = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipart.setMaxUploadSize(3 * 1024 * 1024);
    return multipart;
}

@Bean
@Order(0)
public MultipartFilter multipartFilter() {
    MultipartFilter multipartFilter = new MultipartFilter();
    multipartFilter.setMultipartResolverBeanName("multipartResolver");
    return multipartFilter;
}
```

Also, it seems like we should leave the 'Content-Type' to blank, so that Chrome would set the boundary itself.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I do have those multipart properties enabled in my application.properties file.  

When I add  headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"} to my requestOptions string in React, I get the following error in Spring Boot: "the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found"

Comment: Hi, I've edited the answer. Please check it out and let me know. Thanks

Comment: I have defined the CommonMultipartResolver Bean with new dependencies and it compiles.  With that set, and the content-type set to blank, I'm back to getting my original error - org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace please? thank you